# How to add a Word add-in 2007 to a particular word 2007 document

Tags: vsto, add-in, openxml-sdk

I have created a Word add-in which would load data in custom ribbon from external web service. I need to have that add-in in a document so that It can populate the data only on that document. I don't want to have application level add-in because It will try to load data for any other word document user might create. I want to do this as this document would serve as a template for other documents. Is this possible?

If the above is not possible, how do you actually install the word-2007 add-in.  I see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa192545) link. Is this the way one should do it?

I am using VS 2010 Premium edition on Windows 7. I also have Word 2007installed in my machine.

Comment: Regarding deployment, the link you have deals with Office 2003; things got easier with Office 2007/2010. The following link should provide you with solid pointers on VSTO deployment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/1666d2b0-a4d0-41e8-ad86-5eab3542de1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to create a document- or template- level addin.

Comment: how do you create document-level addin? Do you see any option in VS.NET 2010?

Comment: @ydobonmai: New Project, Office, Office 2007, Word 2007 Document

Comment: I see that now. But It says Project creation failed. This link didn't help as well "http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/10/visual-studio-2008-orcas-creation.html". I dont see the app config entry in the devenv.exe.config.